# Is there a questionned ordering symbol like the questionned equality?

Tags: notation

To question the equality between $a$ and $b$ we can use $a \overset{?}{=} b$

From what I understand, the $\overset{?}{=}$ sign is to be replaced either by $=$ or $\not=$ and the writer will guide me through the process of determining wich one is true.

Is there such a symbol for determining the ordering of $a$ and $b$, one that would account for $\overset{?}{<}$, $\overset{?}{>}$, $\overset{?}{=}$ ?

Comment: If you want your text to be harder to understand, try to use as many different notations as you can possible find and link the reader to any reference where it is used. You might also like to use a font, that is really hard to read or scribble down some notes while going 120mph on a motorbike.

Comment: Is $\overset{?}{\text{better}}$ really better?

Comment: You can do whatever you like, as long as the text makes it clear what it means.  I don't think any of them, including $\overset{?}{=}$, are standard.

Comment: When I am presenting a calculation in class, and I don't particularly care what the answer is, I often use $\overset{\text{pretend}}{=}$.  For example $101 \times 64^{2/3} \overset{\text{pretend}}{=} 1020$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I use $\gtrless$ or $\lessgtr$,and avoid at all cost $\lesseqgtr$, $\gtreqless$.

I don't remember seeing any of those in any standard text though.